# How to observe build time calls to a function in webpack or gulp?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

Let's say I have this helper function:

```js
// helpers.js

export view(name){
    // find and return a view object.

    return new View(name);
}
```

Using it somewhere else:

```js
// request_handler.js
import {view} from "./helpers.js"

export default () => {
    // Do something and then return a view object.
    
    return view("home.index");
}
```

How can I track calls to the `view` helper function?
(In my particular case, I just need the view names)

Edit:
I'm looking for a solution in **build** time, not runtime.
I can accept a solution in gulp as well.

Comment: You want to know each time someone is calling view function? In runtime? Is a subject from rxjs on the global scope is a considerable solution for you?

Comment: @RazRonen not in runtime, but in build time. I'm dealing with some legacy code and trying to pass variables from the request handler to the actual view file (an `.asp` file). I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: All the callers use hardcoded syntax? Or you may have something like this: `const name = "name1"; view(name);`

Comment: @RazRonen Since I'm the only one developing the project I'll only use hard coded strings.